# How to update and get the analysis result from a analysis pass after transform the function in the function transform pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

want to konw how can we update and get the analysis result in the transform pass, after the function have been modified. i don't want go back to the pipeline and go through around all the analysis about all function. it‘s Inefficient.

for example:
write a pass to modify some ir in the function, and than get the result from analysis pass and do transform again.

Answer (score 0):

Inefficiency has many facets. One of the people who taught me programming said (quoting from memory) "don't maintain two data structures for the same thing and transform them in parallel; when a bug introduces a divergence, fixing that bug tends to take a lot of time". That's developer time, not CPU time, of course.

LLVM's pass manager runs analysis passes on demand when a pass requires it, and each pass reports which analyses it preserves by returning a suitable value from its `run()`. The pass manager may then rerun the analysis, or not if nothing needs it again. One or a few analyses allow passes to modify their data structure, I don't remember precisely, but I think either LoopInfo or the Dominator does that. If you measure significant ineficiencies in any other analysis pass, I'm sure similar patches will be welcomed.

There are many examples of code using this in the lib/Transforms directory, search for AM.getResult and look at the surrounding functions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the analysis. Some of them have an API that allows you to update their analysis in response to changes made by your transform. In LLVM we usually look at the actual pass pipeline and look for cases where there is an analysis that is needed before and after a transform that doesn't preserve the analysis, then teach it to do so. You should look at which analyses you want to preserve and what they offer for IR updates in their API. Worst case, you may have to add this to the analysis too.